# What is happening here ? How to rectify this?

Tags: python, oop, import

```
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'
PS D:\python course>
```

```
import pandas as pd

record = [
    (11, "gorge", "o+"),
    (22,"mike", "b+"),
    (33, "steve", "a+"),
    (44, "chirstiano", "e-")]

pd.DataFrame(record, index=['a','b','c','d'], columns=[ ' S_No', 'Name', '  Blood_Group'])
print(pd.DataFrame)
```

What is happening here ? How to rectify this? [here is a picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DQqI.png)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/10077)

Comment: I have uploaded that . Please click on"here is a picture of my problem"....you will definitely get that.

Comment: You must have either overwritten the name `string` with a variable you created, or you have a script called `string.py` whose import is getting prioritized over the built-in `string` module.

Comment: @JunaidAshraf They're saying that you should **NOT** upload a picture. Instead, *paste* the code and error into your question **AS TEXT**.

Comment: @Random Davis Is that fine now?

Comment: @JunaidAshraf perfect